# splitting strings in an array-list Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, split

I have an `ArrayList` consisting of dates. All of the dates are in this format:

"day month time timezone year". An example would look like this, **Wed Aug 10:15:17 AST 2016**.

I need to split the string at the second ":". Here is my code to do that.

```
int dateSize = date.size();
int i = 0;
ArrayList<String> splitDate = new ArrayList<String>();
splitDate.clear();
while(i < dateSize) {
    String[] splitString = date.get(i).split(":" + 1);
    splitDate.add(splitString[0]);
    Log.i("info", String.valueOf(splitDate));
    i++;
}
```

The `ArrayList` consists about 50 items. At first, this code works. It prints this to the log,

**Wed Sep 14 23:30**, which is what I want.

But then, at random, it starts to print this,

> Wed Sep 14 23:30, Wed Sep 14 23:24:36 AST 2016, Wed Sep 14 23, Wed Sep
>   14 22, Wed Sep 14 22, Tue Sep 13 22, Tue Sep 13 22, Tue Sep 13
>   22:07:33 AST 2016, Mon Sep 12 20

Sometimes it splits the second ":", sometimes it splits the first ":", sometimes it doesn't split anything. I cannot figure out why this is happening. IF I change my code to this,

```
String[] splitString = date.get(i).split(":");
splitDate.add(splitString[0]);
```

It works flawlessly. Everything gets printed to the log like this, **Wed Aug 10**, no exceptions.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Because you are using this to split `":" + 1`.

Comment: you should use dates and simpleDateFormatter instead, that will make your life easier...

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ But splitting would be faster imho. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all this isn't what you want

```
String[] splitString = date.get(i).split(":" + 1);
```

This is splitting on the String ":1"

What you want to do is split on ":" and then get the first two entries in the array and concatenate them

```
String[] splitString = date.get(i).split(":");
splitDate.add(splitString[0] + ":" + splitString[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments says you problem is this line

```
String[] splitString = date.get(i).split(":" + 1);
```

Essentially you're going to be passing ":1" as the argument to split().  Therefore you'll end up selecting severything up tot he first instance of ":1", or the whole string if ":1" isn't present.  For example:

- **Wed Aug 10**:15:17 AST 2016 will give Wed Aug 10
- **Wed Aug 10:25**:17 AST 2016 will give Wed Aug 10:25
- Wed Aug 10:25:25 AST 2016 will give Wed Aug 10:25:25 AST 2016

If you know thee format of the string then I'd just do:

```
String dateStr = date.substring(0, 13)
```

If you don't know the format of the strings (e.g. they've been typed in by a user who may have typoed some) then I'd check them with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the an array element of strings in the format "Wed Aug 10:15:17 AST 2016" and you split/delimit by ":", you will end up with the following array of strings:

```
[0] Wed Aug 10
[1] 15
[2] 17 AST 2016
```

If you look at the above array, you cannot accomplish your desired output of "Wed Aug 10 15:17" with just splitting the string and then adding the components (i.e.: You will miss the '17' in the above example, as it falls in element [2]).

I am not a Java dev, so the syntax may be a bit off, but if you want to generate "Wed Aug 10 15:17", then I believe you are looking for this:

```
String[] splitString = date.get(i).split(":");\\remove "1" from your delimiter
String tempString = splitString[2].substring(0,1);
splitDate.add(splitString[0] + " " + splitString[1] + ":" + tempString);
```

In the above snippet, the tempString line is getting the first two characters from the split string array element [2]. You then add the first two array elements with the tempString (i.e.: 17) and get your output.

Edit: I just wanted to mention that if you have control over the input of date strings, I would advise using a different delimiter. Using ":" causes the issue that the delimiter also exists as a valid, non-delimiter, character in the string. The above code snippet should work presuming the input is not controlled by you/your method.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more complicated way using `replaceFirst` method.

```
ArrayList<String> splitDate = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String dateItem : date) {
    String output = dateItem.replaceFirst("^(\\w{3}\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}):\\d{2}\\s\\w+\\s\\d+$", "$1");
    splitDate.add(output);
    Log.i("info", output);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `java.util.StringTokenizer` class.
Considering `date` is the `ArrayList` containing dates in `String` format, the following lines of code will add the date in the format required.

```
StringTokenizer dateString = new StringTokenizer(date.get(i), ":");
splitDate.add(dateString.nextToken() + ":" + dateString.nextToken());
```

Simple enough!